# One big XML schema or more smaller?

Tags: xml, xsd

I create an ER Diagram of a purchase order system and currently I'm trying to create the corresponding XML schema(s) for the purchase order system. The schema(s) should include the following elements:

- Product
- Producer of the Product
- Customer
- Shipping and billing address
- Invoice

At the moment I'm unsure of how modular the schema(s) should be.

1. Should I make one one big XML schema "Order" which has all of the mentioned elements in it?
2. Should I make a XML schema for each entity/element and then include them in the "Order" XML schema?

I guess it would make sense to have a separate XML schema for the products, but I'm not sure. Is there any rule of thumb of how modular XML schemas should be created?

Comment: I would make a logical division between product, customer, and invoice.  An invoice involves customer(s) and product(s).

Comment: Would you put the information of the producer inside the product schema in this case?

Comment: Yes, I would, but keep your eyes open for a comment/answer from a real XML guru, who may disagree with me.  I commented just from the point of view of basic normalization of data.

Comment: Technically a schema is a set of schema components, typically assembled from a number of schema documents. So your actual question is not about the number of schemas, but about the number of schema documents.

Answer (score 1):

The only benefit in splitting the schema into multiple schema documents is if you think you might one day be able to use those modules in isolation from each other. With something this simple, I suspect that's unlikely to happen; but your guess is likely to be better than mine. (Like most design questions posted on SO, there's not enough information about the requirements and constraints to make an informed recommendation.)